# How to properly create C# class with a list of weekly open hours property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I feel like this is going to be very obvious to many of you, but my research led me nowhere.
I'm trying to build a class that will create objects with a list of properties like this one:

```
public class MyObject
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public List<OpenHours> OpenHours { get; set; }
        public Filter Filters { get; set; }

    }
```

I want the **OpenHours** object to store a list of daily hours so that they are accessible by doing **MyObject.OpenHours[index].property**.

I'm currently getting the error that the OpenHours object does not have a defined key, but I actually don't want it to be in my database as a different entity, I just want it to store properties the same way that it would if I listed each of the weekDay's properties directly in the MyObject class.

Here is the OpenHours class:

```
public class OpenHours
{
    public DayOfWeek Day { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

I want each of my "MyObject" objects to have unique OpenHours values, so I do not want to create an Id just for it.
Am I missing something in the syntax, or is it bad logic to do so?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

**Edit:** Someone answered and deleted his answer afterwards, so I can't mark it as the right answer, but the solution was to add [ComplexType] to my class :

```
[ComplexType]
public class OpenHours
{
    public DayOfWeek Day { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone answered and deleted his answer afterwards, so I can't mark it as the right answer, but the solution was to add **[ComplexType]** to my class :

```
[ComplexType]
public class OpenHours
{
    public DayOfWeek Day { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

Links for additional information on Complex Types:

- [Associations in EF Code First: Part 2 – Complex Types](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2-complex-types)
- [Entity Framework Complex Types - EF Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj680147(v=vs.113).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

if each entry is going to be unique then make a compound primary key if you do not want to introduce an id. Make all the properties the primary key. This will be less efficient in DB terms than just creating an Id as the primary key though.